# How to activate an extension in Firefox programmatically?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there any way to activate (enable) an extension in `Firefox` programmatically?
I tried to analyze `Firefox` settings but I found only this field `extensions.boostrappedAddons` which is disappeared when I disable my extension.
I tried to set this property by myself but the extension was still disabled after that.
So, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

From javascript you'll first call [`AddonManager.getAddonByID()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getAddonByID%28%29) and then set [`addon.userDisabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon#Required_properties) to `false`.

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID("id of the addon in question", function(addon) {
  if (!addon) {
    // Not found?!
    return;
  }
  addon.userDisabled = false;
});
```

Just a reminder: An add-on cannot necessarily enable itself. Disabled add-on are not running and therefore cannot call any code to enable themselves[1].

[1] Unless it is a non-restartless add-on that was enabled and only was scheduled to be disabled *and* there was no browser restart yet. But then it is not really disabled, is it? ;)